# I would like to open one program on the second screen in AwesomeWM, but only if the second screen is available

Tags: lua, screen, multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I made a change in my `rc.lua` to always open Chromium on screen 2:

```lua
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- many other rules here...

    -- Set Chromium to always map on screen "2"
    { rule = { class = "Chromium" },
      properties = { screen = 2 } },
}
```

However, when I do not have an external monitor attached, I get an error ("screen expected, got nil").  How do I modify this rule to use screen 1 if screen 2 is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes you have only two or one screens. It does the wrong thing when there are more screens, but it should get the idea across:

```
properties = { screen = function() return screen.count() end }
```

All(?) properties in `awful.rules` can also be specified as a callback function. This function even gets the client (and the table of collected properties?) as argument (but this is not used in this example).

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I was sure something like that would exist, I just didn't know the interface.