# How to open a program in a specific tag in AwesomeWM from command line?

Tags: awesome-wm

I would like to open a program on a given tag ("virtual desktop").  I [roughly know how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61427799/1181665) depending on a program, but now I'd like to be able to decide where to run it from command line.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new client from the command line and make Awesome WM do something with it *directly* from the same command.

There are, however, multiple alternatives ways to achieve a similar result:

- Use a rule that matches the client (e.g. from the class)
- Use a specific identifier on the client to match a rule (e.g. urxvt has a  `-name` parameter that you can play with. In your config, create a rule that marches cleints with name "NAMETOGOTOTAG8", then from the command line `urxvt -name NAMETOGOTOTAG8`)
- Use the `awesome-client` program to open the program from Awesome, so you can use the `awful.spawn` sn_rules (e.g. `awesome-client 'require("awful.spawn").spawn("kitty", { tag = 8 })'`